# Single concatArrayEager doesnt subscribe to all sources

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-kotlin

I am writing some repository logic for android application, I have this logic for retrieving data from database and updating the database with data from api immediately after that.

```
   fun fetchData(): Single<Data> {
    return Single.concatArrayEager(
            fetchFromDb(),
            fetchFromApi())
            .firstOrError()
}
```

By the way - database is Room and api is Retrofit. Now what happens is that room emits almost instantly, but for some reason api request is not fired - the second `Single` doesn't start.

I read the documentation on the eager operator and I am not sure if this is correct behavior. I even tried to delay the database fetch, by like 20 miliseconds - which resulted in that second single being actually fired

Comment: what does `fetchFromDb()` returns? If it's not `Single` then it wouldn't work. Concat operator works like: emit all from first do it till it's not `onComplete` and only after that it starts to emit items from the second one.

Comment: both fetchFromDb and fetchFromApi are Single and its concatArrayEager operator

Comment: Then i guess problem is in `.firstOrError()` It make your Flowable to Single. From it docs: `Returns a Single that emits only the very first item emitted by this Flowable or signals a NoSuchElementException if this Flowable is empty.` So it emits first one (which is DB data)

Comment: Yes I want that to be single, thats not an issue. My problem is that api Single is not started - I dont see any api call. I dont need result of that api call, I just want to fire it off and if its successful, update the database with it

Comment: you can use Observable.concat(fetchFromApi(),fetchFromDb()).it will wait for both observable to complete and then return result.

Comment: Guys thanks for you help but I am wondering why concatArrayEager didnt subscribe to all singles, you are not answering my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `concatArrayEager` should subscribe to all `Observables`. But your API call might take some time to actually start. This might be more time than your DB call needs to return.

Now we see the effect of `firstOrError`. When the first value is received, the stream is terminated and all active or pending subscriptions of the concatenation are canceled. Also the API result won't ever be used.

Comment: Makes sense now, I see that I basically added race condition with this design, thanks